# Calculating expectation w.r.t. the empirical dist. fcn

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, stieltjes-integral

I am trying to evaluate the plug-in estimator $$\hat{\theta} = T(F_n)$$ where $F_n (t) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}1\{t_i \leq t\}$ and $T : \eta \to \int_{}^{}x \ d\eta(x) $, (Riemann-Stieltjes integral).

My approach has been to try to use "Lemma 7.4" found on page 134 in "A Concise introduction to mathematical statistics" by Dragi Anevski which states that if  $F$ is an increasing step function on $I$, so that $$F(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i \ 1\{t\leq t_i\}$$ with $min(I) = t_0 < t_1 ... <t_N = max(I)$ and $a_i \geq 0$. Then if $g$ is continuous, $$\int_{I}^{}g(x)dF(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} g(t_i)a_i$$.

So if we let $g(x) = x$, $a_i = 1$ and $$F_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}1\{x_i \leq x\} =  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}1\{\frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{1}{x_i}\} =  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}1\{t \leq t_i\}$$, with $t = \frac{1}{x}$ and  $t_i = \frac{1}{x_i}$, then we have that $$\hat{\theta} = T(F_n) = \int_{}^{}x \ d{F_n}(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x_i}$$.

This is apparently wrong because the very same book says it should be $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$. Why is this true and where do I go wrong? I found another post on here about this calculation but it involved the Dirac function and I have not yet learned about it.

Thanks in advance, $$\\$$
Isak

Comment: Perhaps you could use that $nF_n(x)\sim\mathcal{bin}(n,F(x))$ where $F$ is the population DF.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have no clue in which direction I go with that information. Is the population distribution function such that $f_x(k) = {n \choose k}{F(x)}^k{(1-F(x))}^{n-k}$? What is $F(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an error either in that lemma or in your rendition of it. The function

$$
F(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i \ 1\{t\le t_i\}
$$

with $a_i\gt0$ is a *decreasing* step function (the value at $-\infty$ is $\sum_ia_i$ and the value at $+\infty$ is $0$). A correct formulation of the lemma would be for an *increasing* step function $F$ of the form

$$
F(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i \ 1\{t\ge t_i\}\;.
$$

Then you don't need to turn the inequality around, and the result comes out right.

Your manipulation involving $t$ and $x$ isn't valid because you applied the lemma for $t$ even though the measure is $\mathrm dF_n(x)$, not $\mathrm dF_n(t)$. A valid way to turn around the inequality (if there'd been a need for turning it around) would have been to use $1\{t\ge t_i\}=1-1\{t\lt t_i\}$ and thus $\mathrm d1\{t\ge t_i\}=-\mathrm d1\{t\lt t_i\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes. I asked the teacher and he made an error in the book. It has all worked out now. :D